# How to change a background image for desktop (@media)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a site and the background images are pretty much as I want them on mobile, but when it comes to desktop, I can't seem to use an @media query to modify them.

My css is:

```
body.page-id-6166 { 
  background-image: url(https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/FlyerMaker_22042019_085055.png);    
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

That covers mobile and desktop obviously, and works

But when I try:

```
@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  body.page-id-6166 { 
    background-image: url(https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/FlyerMaker_22042019_085055.png);  
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }
}
```

Nothing happens.

Even tried it with `important` which it didn't like at all.

To clarify futher. They are the same image, but one  (desktop) you can only see part of it because of landscape/portrait etc and because it gets automatically enlarged in desktop for some reason. So on mobile, original image (the whole thing) x 2.In desktop, you only see one image and only a part of that one image. So that's why i want that @media query. You can see an example in https://adsler.co.uk/dating/ or https://adsler.co.uk/jobs/ It's the same image but desktop only selects part of it and seems to blow it up.

Comment: try giving width and height to the background image.

Comment: Note sure which html is relevant here...? Here is link also https://adsler.co.uk/dating/

Comment: Your images are the same.

Comment: user11364702 your @media query is working on desktop fine.... what do you want now.

Comment: @yunzen they're different. On desktop only part of thr image shows...

Comment: @Mohit... Really?

Comment: Yes check now, and say again.. working or not?

Comment: @user11364702 The images share the exact same URL. They must be the same

Comment: @user11364702 Can't see what your issue is here. The CSS works fine, but it's somewhat redundant, as the new values are the same as the old values. Please elaborate more on what your actual issue is. Especially answer these two questions: What do you expect to happen? And what does happen instead?

Comment: @yunzen Thanks for that. They're not the same though. In the media query i don't have background-image: cover; for example. The images aree also not the same.. On mobile you see the whole image, repeated On desktop, you don't see the whole image, just a blown up version of the original and parts are missing because it's enlarged.

Comment: @Mohit please see edited question.

Comment: @John_ny seems on the right tracks maybe. I'll try

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that on your website https://adsler.co.uk/dating/ you have the code duplicated.

You have

```
@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  body.page-id-6166 { 
    background-image:  url('https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/FlyerMaker_22042019_085055.png');       
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
   }
}
```

But you also have the following without the media query which renders the media query code above useless.

```
body.page-id-6166 { 
    background-image: url(https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/FlyerMaker_22042019_085055.png);  
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: The first is a media query designed to effect desktop view, the second for mobile view. Please also see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Working properly check this in screen size between 768px to 1920px:

```css
@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  body.page-id-6166 { 
    background-image:  url('https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/FlyerMaker_22042019_085055.png');       
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
   }
}
```

```html
<body class="page-id-6166">


</body>
```

Comment: It's not. You can only see part of the image on desktop

Comment: By `Working Properly` Joykal means the code is doing exactly as instructed.  You need to give the code more specific instructions, @user11364702

Comment: Ok. How do i do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I added `background-size: contain;`

`@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 786px) {body.page-id-1645 {
background-image: url( https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/FlyerMaker_24042019_164029.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: contain;}}`

This makes it look amazing when used with `background-repeat: repeat`

(given my styling)

Still not exactly like mobile but maybe better.....

Thanks all.